# Displaying a relatively positioned div (with absolute content) at top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which contains a relatively positioned div with absolute content.  Here is a j[sfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lenb/vLke49gu/1/).

When I click #view1, I want #view2 to move to the top of the viewport.  The debugger shows the click being handled but nothing changes in the display.

Can anyone help.

Here is the example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#view1").on("click", function (){
    $("#view2").scrollTop(0);
});
});
</script>

<style>
body,div,img {  padding:0; border:0; margin: 0;  }
img, #view1 { position: absolute; }
#view2  {position: relative; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
Lots of stuff up here, so div below scrolls off page.
</p> ... more stuff
<div id="view2">
            <div id="view1" > <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/175/" /></div>
</div>
<p>
Lots more stuff down here ....
</p>
```

Comment: 1) I do not understand what you want to do and 2) Why are you programming an anchor when it already exist in HTML? http://jsfiddle.net/vLke49gu/3/

Comment: Oops.  You're right, I am programming an anchor.  I hadn't thought to use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it won't show any change. As you are not doing anything with `$("#view2").scrollTop(0);` . By the way, why you have put 0 inside the parenthesis ? It is not needed.

**scrollTop()**
It returns the vertical position of scrollbar (of matched element).
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp

Write this `alert($("#view2").scrollTop());` , instead of `$("#view2").scrollTop(0);`

It will return you an integer.